# Access instances in GCP

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How I can access GCP instance using ssh key

It seems when I create a instance in GCP, I can only access it through the "ssh" button from the console. I want to know if there is a way I can define a ssh key pair in GCP and whenever I create a instance, I have a choice to use this key pair. In AWS, I could do this and after I create a instance, I could ssh to it as user "ec2".

What I am doing now is after the instance was created in GCP, I "ssh" to it from console ssh option, and add my public key to the authorized_keys on the instance. After that, I could ssh to it from any host that has my private key.

I want yo know if there is a way I can add my public key to the instance when i create it and I don't have to manual do it afterward and just ssh on to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your SSH Public Key to your instance before creation.

- When in the "Create an instance" screen, go to "Management, security, disks, networking, sole tenancy".
- Click on "Security".
- Paste your "SSH-RSA" format public key to "SSH Keys".
- Continue with creating the instance.

The SSH Public Key should start like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza
```

If not convert the key.

[Managing SSH Keys in Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys)

Once the instance is up, you will be able to connect using the matching SSH Private Key.

Since I do this for every instance that I create, plus I also add Stackdriver and other software, I create an "Instance Template" instead. Then I can just use the template to create my instances. Saves me from repeating the same configuration steps over and over.

Comment: Great. This works for me and the template is a good ides. Thanks John.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your public key into Compute Engine --> Metadata. Once you this you will be able to login into any of the VM instances in that gcp project using your putty or terminal window from your laptop or on-premise system. Refer the documentation for the same here.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys